# Magento 2 How to display shipping costs in minicart popup?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, mini-cart

How can I display shipping methods/prices on minicart pop up in Magento 2?

Comment: duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153858/magento-2-how-to-show-tax-and-shipping-costs-in-mini-cart-pop-up