# Magento 2 - How to show tax and shipping costs in mini-cart pop up

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, tax, mini-cart

How to show **tax and shipping costs in mini cart popup** in Magento 2?

[image]

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: I'm on Magento 2, 2.1.2 to be exact.

Answer (score 10):

To show additional stuff or costs in the minicart (like taxes or shipping costs), you need to understand where the data in the minicart comes from.

### The Customer Data Section Pool

If you add a product to the cart, you can see in your inspector a XHR request is made to `/customer/section/load` with the arguments `?sections=cart,messages`. This controller checks in the section pool (`Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface`) for objects that provide data for the required sections. This data is saved in the local storage of your browser and utilized in the minicart. This design pattern is called an [Object Pool](https://giel.berkers.online/articles/magento/object-pools) and they are used thoroughly in Magento 2.

You can hook into this Object Pool very easily by adding the following to your modules' `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="my-section" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\CustomerData\Something</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

As for the `Something`-class in this example: the only requirement is that it implements 
`\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface` so it has the `getSectionData()`-method. This method should return an array with data that is added to the JSON object when you ask the controller to load it (for example: `/customer/section/load?sections=my-section`.

### Extending existing functionality

Now as for your question the answer is even simpler: since you want to add some extra quote information (like taxes and shipping costs) you can simply use a plugin to hook into `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart::getSectionData()` to add your information to the data that is fetched when `/customer/section/load?sections=cart` is called. In your `di.xml` add:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
    <plugin name="my_custom_stuff" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"/>
</type>
```

And in your plugin:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject
 * @param array $result
 * @return array
 */
public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, array $result)
{
    $result['something'] = 'Stuff';
    return $result;
}
```

Now what you do in your plugin is beyond the scope of this help, so you have to figure out on your own how to fetch the Tax and/or shipping costs at this point, but I'm pretty sure you'll figure that out.

### Implementing it in the Frontend

Now we have a hook where we can add data from the backend to the frontend. **Please note that this is only executed when the customer section data is loaded!** or even better: **as soon as you add a product to the cart**. In other words: you won't have this data on the frontend without updating your cart first.

Now, the data in our plugin is added to our `cart`-node in the JSON, and we can access this in the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals` UI Component. This has a property called `cart` which is an observable that contains everything from our JSON response. This becomes very clear if you look at the template `Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html`:

```
<div class="amount">
    <span data-bind="html: cart().subtotal"></span>
</div>
```

In this file, `cart().subtotal` reflects that `cart.subtotal`-item in the JSON data.

### Adding an extra rule to the minicart

Now here comes the most important part (and probably the answer to your question): How can we show our extra data in the minicart?

Well the minicart is made up of a bunch of UI Components tangled into each other, so without too much further explanation this is how you set it up. Add `checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers.xml` to your modules' `frontend/layout`-folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!--
                                            Include stuff in MiniCart:
                                        -->
                                        <item name="stuff" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/minicart/stuff</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal.totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/minicart/stuff/totals</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the template `frontend/web/checkout/minicart/stuff.html`:

```
<div class="my-stuff">
    <span class="label">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'My Custom Stuff' --><!-- /ko -->
    </span>

    <!-- ko foreach: elems -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

And the template `frontend/web/checkout/minicart/stuff/totals.html`:

```
<div class="amount price-container">
    <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().something"></span>
</div>
```

This should do the trick. Haven't tested this example, but it's taken from an implementation I did where I need to add the FPT, Shipping costs and Grand Total to the minicart and it worked like a charm!

It's so easy! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it works! I really did not know that it is SO easy ;-)

Comment: Hi How do i get tax here.

Comment: @Giel How to get the shipping cost on the minicart. Can you please tell me the solution?
I am really stuck with this.