# How to disaply tax and grandtotal in minicart

Tags: magento2.3, tax, mini-cart, grand-total

i have tax setup in website everywhere showing but in **minicart** not showing in tax

so i want to tax and `grand total` show in `mini cart`

how can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For tax you can use this solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153858/magento-2-how-to-show-tax-and-shipping-costs-in-mini-cart-pop-up